# Printing a line by updating an already outputted line

Tags: python

Forgive me if the title is not lucid, but I could not better describe it in a single sentence.

Consider I have the following in a loop, which increments `counter` each time it runs.

`output_string = 'Enter the number [{0}]'.format(counter)`

When I do a `print output_string`, the output goes like:

```
Enter the number [1]:
```

When I print this line again with the incremented number, like:

```
Enter the number [2]:
```

It will of course follow the 1st line and the cumulative output would be:

```
Enter the number [1]:
Enter the number [2]:
```

However, I don't want this. I want the first line line should be updated and without adding another line, the output should just change in the first line itself.

Like, it should display `Enter the number [1]:` and after that it should do an in-place replacement for [1] and the screen should read: `Enter the number [2]`, without adding an extra line.

I hope I am being clear. The reason I am doing this is because I am taking in large inputs from the user and I don't want to clutter up the terminal when I can just keep on incrementing what I want within a single line.

Comment: Terminals are happy with lots of lines. Why is "cluttering up the terminal" bad?

Comment: Further, if someone wants to accumulate the script with the `script` command, they'll have a mess.  Why prevent someone from using `script`?

Comment: More than wanting it to make it work this script, I want to know how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script will be running on Unix/Linux you could use [the `curses` module](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html).

Comment: I can but I really don't want myself restricted to Linux only. So if there is another way to do it, I would probably try that before checking out curses.

Comment: @PulpFunction: Curses is available for Windows.  http://adamv.com/dev/python/curses/

Comment: @PulpFiction: fair enough.  There are ways to get `curses` working on Windows but all they seemed ghastly when I looked at them.  If you find a Windows-friendly way of doing this it'd be useful for me too.

Comment: This issue is not Linux/Windows specific per si, it is terminal emulation related. Assuming you will be launching python from cmd.exe, you want to know how to control he cursor position on cmd .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
print('enter the number[1]', end='\r' )
```

If you're using Python 2.7, don't forget `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: I don't get it -- what is this supposed to do that the original solution didn't?

Comment: @katrielalex: It may not move "down" on some terminal windows.  It may overwrite the line, depending on the settings.

Comment: @S.Lott: It still is not an in-place replacement. I think this is possible since I have seen it somewhere. I would have looked at the sources but I don't recall where.

Comment: @PulpFiction: Anything more than this is terminal specific.  It requires either curses or writing two separate versions, one for Linux (using the TERMIO settings) and one for Windows.

Comment: @S.Lott: Aah thank you. And also, thanks for your amazing book. I am currently following that (Building Skills in Python).